# Spam filter in signatures?

Tags: nodes, advertising

Since otherwise great [spam](http://drupal.org/project/spam) module does not check user signatures for spam, I have hard times fighting spammers who just put their spam links in their [signatures](http://drupal.org/project/signature_forum) in the forum so basically they rendered my custom spam filters useless.

I appreciate if you have some suggestions to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a better answer in the context of forum signatures only ( assuming D6 forum_signature module ) could be

Preprocess the signature.tpl.php template file and add the spam check

in template.php, function sig might be `THEME_preprocess_signature`, so try both, if first doesn't work.

```
function THEME_preprocess_signature_forum(&$variables){
  $content = $variables['signature'];
  $test = spam_content_is_spam($content, 'signature_forum');
  if (!empty($test['is_spam']) && $test['is_spam']){
   $variables['signature'] = t('This signature has been removed by our spam filter, please contact the site administrator for assistance');
  }

}
```

Then clear theme registry cache.

I don't use those modules myself, but such an approach, with a little tweaking, could work.

Comment: the snippet did not work for me, in either of variations.

Answer (score -1):

Ban any spammers by IP address, either:

1. One at a time from Admin > Config > People > IP Blocking
2. Block the range at the webserver config level ( firewall, virtualhost or .htaccess )

You may also want to add [reCaptcha](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) to user registration, if suitable.

Comment: Unfortunately these tips are irrelevant to my question.

Comment: I didn't realize preventing spammers accessing your site was irrelevant. Good luck with that.

Comment: I have already several anti-spam measures in place, including the ones that you mentioned. My specific question is mentioned in the title of this topic.

Comment: I missed the part where you mentioned you had used those methods, mostly because it wasn't mentioned.

Comment: The OP is asking about spam in signatures. While the suggestions are generally useful, they don't help the OP, who doesn't want to manually block the IP of those users.