# What preprocessor should I use?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to make signature.tpl.php available to spam filters (by default it is  not).

1. Will adding a preprocess hook to template.php will do the trick?
2. If so, what preprocess hook should I choose?

[In this drupal answer post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55015/spam-filter-in-signatures), someone has suggested the following snippet to solve this problem:

```
function THEME_preprocess_signature_forum(&$variables){
  $content = $variables['signature'];
  $test = spam_content_is_spam($content, 'signature_forum');
  if (!empty($test['is_spam']) && $test['is_spam']){
   $variables['signature'] = t('This signature has been removed by our spam filter, please contact the site administrator for assistance');
  }

}
```

But it had no effect for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Hehe, that was me. Untested, as I don't use that module, but possible. Perhaps the preprocess function is `themename_preprocess_signature` instead of `preprocess_signature_forum`. Worth a try, clear theme registry cache after modifying such functions. Add some debug code to ensure function is executed.

Comment: Nice to see you here David :) Actually I used both variants as per your suggestion but none works.

Comment: OK, it was really just a guess, is the function called? I'd try it out myself, but not using those modules, snippet was assuming D6.

Comment: How should I see if the function is called?

Comment: `drupal_set_message(__FUNCTION__);` or `var_dump(__FUNCTION__);`

Comment: Sorry where should I put this codes?